# Why was this answer deleted and marked as offensive?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760821/trigger-codedeploy-when-specific-branch-pattern-is-created) is the question:

[image]

And this is the answer which was deleted and marked as offensive:

[image]

But checking the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69706871/revisions)

The content was:

[image]

Which is nothing offensive.

Also, the answer is valid because [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda) is the only way to replicate what [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) and [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) does in this case.

Can I revive the answer?

Comment: It was flagged as **spam** OR offensive content....

Comment: *Spam or offensive*. I'm pretty sure that has been flagged as spam.

Comment: #Augusto Vasques, is not spam, it's not offensive either. PD: Is not my question/anwser. I trying only to improve it because is valid

Comment: It is spam. Spam can be useful, this does not make it legit.

Comment: A simple, harmless question is sending this score to the bottom of the score. Something is wrong with that. The goal was to revive a valid answer with **zero answers**

Answer (score 16):

I'm pretty confident that answer was flagged as spam, not for being offensive. The OP linked to their own blog (see their profile) without proper attribution.

from [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> #### Avoid overt self-promotion.
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation in your post.

From [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

> **Don't include links except to support what you've written.** Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and the links you include should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer.

From the [Metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/345485) records:

> User is affiliated with the linked site (*redacted*), and all their recent answers also seem to link to the site. Custom flagged because I think they're at least partial answers posted in good faith

I assume the answer was deleted by a moderator before the community casted enough red-flags but this needs an SO moderator to confirm, if they are willing to be transparent about that.

If you wonder what MetaSmoke is, see [What is SmokeDetector?](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey)

Comment: :o This is like the FIFA rules

Comment: @JRichardsz Nah, FIFA rules are child-play. This is where the real stuff is.

Comment: If there was only one or two downvotes, it had to be deleted with a moderator (or diamond staff) red flag. I believe on Stack Overflow the level of community red flags needed for spam/abusive deletion has always been 6 or (as of the strike) 4, but other sites have only needed 3 in the past.

Comment: The answer was deleted as the result of a single spam flag from a moderator. Deleting it as spam seems reasonable to me, given the circumstances. Public timestamps indicate that the user posted that SO answer less than 10 minutes after they posted the blog which is linked in the SO post. There's additional private information that further supports a finding of it being spam/promotional. Overall, there's no doubt that the intent was to to promote the blog.

Comment: Even if they weren't trying to promote their *own* blog, I'd argue that the answer should have been deleted anyway as a link-only answer. The examples should have been included inside the answer itself, not in a linked blog post, because if the blog post ever got deleted, the answer would become useless.